# Deriving Area of Circle

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I wanted to find the area of a circle with radius $r$ described by $x^2+y^2=r^2$
I decided to describe the whole circle by multiplying $2$ to the semicircle, $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. I integrated this from $-r$ to $r$.
Eventually I obtained $$2r^2\int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2\theta d\theta$$

Solving for this I got $$A=-\pi r^2$$

Almost, but not quite. Why does this negative come up, and how do I justify removing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because angles are measured counterclockwise from $0$, if you put the greater value of $\theta$ in the lower bound, you are integrating the given area backwards. If you swap the bounds of integration, you will get the same area. The bounds of integration should be $0$ and $\pi$, assuming you're integrating the area in the upper half plane.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction.